# Can't run example app for Flutter_blue, BLE plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to run the example Flutter_blue app, https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue and I keep getting errors all on the main.dart concerning the FindDevicesScreen and DevicesScreen classes.

I started a new Flutter project, injected flutter blue 0.6.0 dependency, changed the Android app minSdkVersion to 19, copied the main.dart and widgets.dart files from the example https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue.

The errors I get are:

```
 "The method ScanResultTile isn't defined for the class 'FindDevicesScreen'", "The method ServiceTile, CharacteristicTile and DescriptorTile isn't defined for the class DeviceScreen"
```

Could anyone recommend a fix or provide a walkthrough of how to successfully run this project?

Answer (score 6):

You're running into this error because you haven't imported the `widgets.dart` file that's located in the same directory as the `main.dart` file in the example.

In the example main.dart file, he calls:

```
import 'package:flutter_blue_example/widgets.dart';
```

if you replace this with :

```
import 'widgets.dart';
```

and save the `widgets.dart` file into the same directory, it should run.